Do you know Names of Contemporary Parmenidean philosophers?
Names of philosophers that deny changes and possibility as a modality of existence and all the concepts related to nothingness, especially those of an empiricist background and tradition. I know that there are many eternalist philosophers, but I do not know a contemporary philosopher who is eternalist on the grounds of the meaninglessness of nothingness, i.e., I don't know philosophers who present themselves as Parmenideans. I'm curious to know how they deal with the question related to Time and its existence taking into account the Parmenidean framework.

Michael Della Rocca, in the book The Parmenidean Ascent:

The central aim of The Parmenidean Ascent is to reveal the power of an extreme monism of a Parmenidean variety in a more uncompromising manner than has been attempted for many a year. For the Parmenidean monist, there are no distinctions whatsoever, and indeed distinctions are unintelligible. The book not only defends—against the tide of much recent scholarship—the attribution of such a sweeping monism to Parmenides, it also embraces this monism in its own right and expands these monistic results to many of the most crucial areas of philosophy. The topics that come in for this rationalistic, monistic treatment include being, action, knowledge, meaning, truth, and metaphysical explanation. There is thus no differentiated being, no differentiated action, knowledge, etc. Rather all is being, just as all is action, knowledge, etc. The motive force behind this argument is a combination of a detailed survey of the failures of leading positions (both historical and contemporary) to meet a demand for the explanation of a given phenomenon, and a powerful rationalist, Bradleyan argument against the reality of relations. The result is a rationalist rejection of all distinctions and a skeptical denial of the intelligibility of ordinary, relational notions of being, action, knowledge, etc. A further significant upshot is the rejection of any distinction between philosophy itself and the study of its history. Throughout the book, attention is paid to philosophical methods, including especially the method, so popular today, of relying on intuitions and common sense. The historically minded and rationalist approach throughout this book goes a long way toward demonstrating the ultimate bankruptcy of this prevalent methodology.


the question is about philosophers who are parmenidean, and you have not mentioned any

@DennisKozevnikoff my answer is literally the name of a parmenidean philosopher...

May we hope -- out of an abundance of rationalistic monistic caution -- that exactly 1 copy of the book was printed and sold?
